# INSERT INTO not populating database table

Tags: php

I have a script that checks the submitgame table and if both approve1 and approve 2 are not blank it inserts data into clanstats. There is no mysql_error it simply redirects to the header without inserting anything into the clanstats table, so I have no idea what is going on. Below is the code.

```
<?php
include("user.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submitgame WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$playerclan = $row['playerclan'];
$opponentclan = $row['opponentclan'];
$win = $row['win'];
$approve1 = $row['approve1'];
$approve2 = $row['approve2'];
if($win == "won") { 
    $win = 1;
    $points = 2;
    $win2 = 0;
    $points2 = 1;
}
else {
    $win = 0;
    $points = 1;
    $win2 = 1;
    $points2 = 2;
}
if($approve1 != "" && $approve2 != "") { 
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO clanstats (clan, points, wins) VALUES ('$playerclan', '$points', '$win')");
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO clanstats (clan, points, wins) VALUES ('$opponentclan', '$points2', '$win2')");
    echo mysql_error($query);
}
else {
    header("location:../approvegames.php");
}
mysql_close($con);
header("location:../approvegames.php");
?>
```

Comment: @Alex you need to select code and click on the `{}` icon above the text area to show the code. Basically what it does is, just add four spaces in front of each line which then gets displayed correctly as code.

Comment: Are you sure the two insert queries are executed? I mean, if the $approve1 or $approve2 variables are differente from the empty string?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump`ing the values of `$approve1` and `$approve2`? Also, always use `exit`/`die` after `header('Location:...')` statements to avoid unexpected results from further code execution

Comment: Wait a minute.. how does your `$result` becomes a `$row`?.. shouldn't you have `mysql_fetch_assoc` in the middle?

Comment: And on top of this all, you're screwed if I decided to manually change url to be `...?id='; DROP TABLE submitgame; --` (i.e. [see SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
    //first off are you connecting, ill presume so
    include("user.php");
    //sql injection!!!
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submitgame WHERE id='$id' limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
    //you were missing this
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $playerclan = $row['playerclan'];
    $opponentclan = $row['opponentclan'];
    $win = $row['win'];
    $approve1 = $row['approve1'];
    $approve2 = $row['approve2'];

    if($win == "won") { 
        $win = 1;
        $points = 2;
        $win2 = 0;
        $points2 = 1;
    }else{
        $win = 0;
        $points = 1;
        $win2 = 1;
        $points2 = 2;
    }

    if($approve1 != "" && $approve2 != "") { 
        //you can have multiple inserts
        $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO clanstats (clan, points, wins) VALUES 
        ('$playerclan', '$points', '$win'),
        ('$opponentclan', '$points2', '$win2')");
        header("location:../approvegames.php");
        //adding die after the header will make sure nothing else gets executed
        die();
    }else{
        header("location:../approvegames.php");
        die();
    }
   //no need to kill the connection as it will close when the script exits
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a line. Perhaps something like:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result)
```